# Converting WAV to MP3 on Linux with low bitrates

Tags: mp3, wav, encoder

I need to convert WAV files to MP3 files so they can be played on a website.

I think that LAME would probably be the best tool. However the WAV files are low bitrate (around 8kbits recorded from a phone) and LAME's website states that it is the "best MP3 encoder at mid-high bitrates and at VBR". Is there is a better encoder for lower bitrates? If so can you define "better"?

Answer (score -1):

I think you will not find any functional MP3 encoder in sources besides LAME at all. You can try address to Fraunhofer's Institute, but I doubt that this is appropriate for you way.